# How to save multiple objects using PARSE library from android

Tags: android, parse-platform

On my Android application I'm getting the user's likes from facebook running an FQL query and I want to save the results on the PARSE platform. 
Instead of saving each object separately is there a way to make a batch request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Parse REST API, you can do batch operations (creating, reading, updating, deleting, etc).

Here is an example of saving a couple objects:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "requests": [
          {
            "method": "POST",
            "path": "/1/classes/GameScore",
            "body": {
              "score": 1337,
              "playerName": "Sean Plott"
            }
          },
          {
            "method": "POST",
            "path": "/1/classes/GameScore",
            "body": {
              "score": 1338,
              "playerName": "ZeroCool"
            }
          }
        ]
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/batch
```

See the [Batch Operations section of the Parse REST API Guide](https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-batch) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

As I found out you can also use the saveAllInBackground static method of ParseObject. You pass in a list of ParseObjects you wish to save.

http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveAllInBackground(java.util.List)